# wp-cron for a multiple server wordpress installation

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, load-balancing, multiserver

I am setting up wordpress multisite website on a multiple server stack (behind an ELB). 
I have the following setup

1. 3 Apache Instances
2. 1 MySQL Server
3. 1 Memcache Server
4. S3 bucket for uploads

All of the setup is working perfectly. My question is "Anything special required for wp-cron"?

A normal cron generally runs only on 1 Server. Should I disable wp-cron and add it to a cron job on 1 of the instances? I am not trying to optimize the cron, if wp-cron will continue to work on multiple instances, then i am fine.

Plugins upgrades & wordpress upgrades will be disabled and done manually.

Answer (score 0):

wp-cron works in a slightly different way to a normal cron.  It will only run when your site has traffic.

Unless there's anything specific to your environment, there should be no reason why you can't just run wp-cron as per normal, especially given that there is only one database involved.